# Transform textinput into select-field

Tags: 7, forms

I'm trying to transform my textinput into a select-field but I keep stumbling upon `An illegal choice has been detected`-error.

What I try in my `hook_form_alter`is this:

```
$form['distance']['search_distance']['#type'] = 'select';
$form['distance']['search_distance']['#options'] = drupal_map_assoc(array(100 => '100 km', 200 => '200 km'));
```

It looks like he's doesn't like strings to be in the select list, although, the value of the input is an integer...

How can I make this input field accept my modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is causing the error, but you're using `drupal_map_assoc()` wrong...

The point of that function is to take a linear array and *convert* it to an associative array with the values of the given array as associated keys. e.g.

```
$form['distance']['search_distance']['#options'] = drupal_map_assoc(array(100, 200, 300));
```

I kind of suspect what you're meaning to do is this:

```
$form['distance']['search_distance']['#options'] = array(100 => '100 km', 200 => '200 km');
```

Your array is already associative, no need to try making it associative all over again :)

Comment: For some reason, your answer is working, but when I change it to `array(5 => '5 km', 10 => '10 km', 20 => '20 km', 50 => '50 km');`, I get the illegal choice again...

Comment: Strange...might have something to do with the fact the values are integers in the first example, and strings in the second but I'm not sure (can't think of any other reasonable difference) - I don't think what you're doing is exactly 'supported' as it were :P

Comment: Ok, apparently, the initial value of the dropdown was "100", that's why it didn't gave an error with your value and it did with mine. But it's solved now :)